# Redirect to same page after Login in Asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper

I want to redirect to same page after Login.

Login.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }))
```

Login Controller

```
public ActionResult login(string returnUrl)
{
 //If login successful
 return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

I had done this but its not working and gives error in Request.rawurl because its not support in .net core mvc and also it gives returnUrl value null in post method. Please help me with proper solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
<form asp-controller="xxx" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Host@Context.Request.Path" method="post">
 //...
<input type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

Comment: No, It is also not working. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: You can see my [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMTBr.gif).

Comment: returnUrl gives null value. Not understand why it gives null value